# android & system variables

Tags: android, networking, system, environment-variables

Does Android set & manages some system/environment variables, and how acces & manage them? Is there a full list of those variable somewhere? For instance, in my case, what would be usefull, would be some "network yes/no var" like: NETWORK_AVALAIBLE, WIFI_AVAILABLE, 3G_AVAILABLE, aso...

Comment: Have you went through these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts

Comment: I checked the related topics when creating mine and made a search yep, but the search criteria are too common.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will be helpful to check connectivity.

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mobile = manager
        .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
NetworkInfo wifi = manager
        .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
if (!wifi.isAvailable() && !mobile.isAvailable()) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

also add following code to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

You can always refer android developer site for this type of questions

Comment: @Steph68 If this answer was useful you could help it by marking it as answer :)